# How do I show that $A$ and $A^T$ are similar, given that the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials, similar-matrices

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$. Assume that the minimal polynomial of the square matrix $A$ is defined as the minimal polynomial of the linear operator $x\mapsto Ax$ for all $x\in\mathbb{F}^n$, on $\mathbb{F}^n$. Now, assume that the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$. Show that $A$ and $A^T$ are similar.

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ similar if there exists an invertible matrix $S$ such that $B=SAS^{-1}$. Finding such an $S$ for $B=A^T$ will solve the problem.

Since the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$, let us denote it by $$m_A(t) = (t-\lambda_1)^{m_1}...(t-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
We know that $m_A(A)$ corresponds to the zero linear operator, i.e. $m_A(A)x=0$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{F}^n$. I quickly noticed that if matrices $P_1,P_2,...P_q$ commute, then $(P_1P_2...P_k)^T = P_1P_2...P_k$. It may be useful to replace each $P_i$ with $(A-\lambda_i)^{m_i}$?

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I'd appreciate any hints!

Comment: If the minimal polynomial splits, then $A$ can be put into Jordan normal form, and so the problem reduces to showing that a Jordan block is similar to its transpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overthinking it. If the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $\mathbb F$, $A$ and $A^T$ are similar to their Jordan forms over $\mathbb F$. However, as $\operatorname{rank}(\lambda I-A)^k=\operatorname{rank}(\lambda I-A^T)^k$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ and each positive integer $k$, the two Jordan forms are the same (up to permutation of Jordan blocks). Hence $A$ and $A^T$ are similar.

Alternatively, that the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits over $\mathbb F$ implies that $A$ is similar to its Jordan form over $\mathbb F$. Since every Jordan block is similar to its own transpose via a reversal matrix (the matrix obtained by flipping the identity matrix left and right), $A$ is similar to $A^T$.

Comment: I am able to follow the argument, but could you talk more about the reversal matrix please?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine E.g. $\pmatrix{&&1\\ &1\\ 1}\pmatrix{x&1\\ &x&1\\ &&x}\pmatrix{&&1\\ &1\\ 1}=\pmatrix{x\\ 1&x\\ &1&x}$.

Comment: "...the two Jordan forms are the same..." - doesn't seem right. They are **similar**, not the same.

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine (1) For any polynomial $p$, we have $p(A)^T=p(A^T)$. Therefore $p(A)=0$ if and only if $p(A^T)=0$. Now the minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial $p$ of the least degree that annihilates the matrix. Hence $A$ and $A^T$ share the same minimal polynomial. ...

Comment: ... (2) The Jordan form of a matrix $M$ is uniquely determined by its Weyr characteristics. Equivalently, it is uniquely determined by $\{(\lambda,\,k\,\operatorname{rank}((\lambda I-M)^k)))\}$ where $\lambda$ is any eigenvalue of $M$ and $k\in\mathbb N$. Hence $A$ and $A^T$ have the same Jordan forms (again, up to permutation of Jordan blocks).